# How to run action in Ruby on some jQuery event with passing params to action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

I want to check username uniqueness onBlur jQuery event. I added special attribute to find field I need to check like this:

```
<input data-validate="/checkname" id="user_email" name="user[email]" size="30" type="email" value="">
```

and added action in RegistrationsController(using devise):

```
 def checkname
  if User.where('user = ?', params[:user]).count == 0
    render :nothing => true, :status => 200
  else
  render :nothing => true, :status => 409
  end
   return
  end

 ...routes...

   checkname GET   /checkname(.:format)  devise/registrations#checkname
```

I want to call it from jQuery, send params add css class depends on checkname action:

```
    $('[data-validate]').blur(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $.get($this.data('validate'), {
        email: $this.val()
    }).success(function() {
        $this.addClass('valid');
    }).error(function() {
        $this.addClass('error');
    });
});
```

**Edit:**Request is seems to be calling, but maybe calling wrong. From Firebug network tab:

```
  http://127.0.0.1:3000/checkname?email=new%40mail.com 404 not found
```

when entering new@mail.com into email field.

This code constantly adding error class to my field, so I have some errors - can someone suggest where ?

Comment: @Speransky, do you mean errors from FireBug ? I don't have any.

Comment: Sorry. Found - http://127.0.0.1:3000/checkname?user=223 404 not found

Comment: @Speransky, we could talk in Russian if you want )